# How to show more than one textview title in a list view?

Tags: java, android, listview, textview

I have a list view and i'm trying to show more than one textview in a listview? How to achieve it? any example code ?  thanks in advance...

Comment: This [tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) can help you.

Comment: try this tutorial
it will help u
http://appfulcrum.com/2010/08/08/how-to-create-rounded-corner-buttons-for-android/

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a custom list adapter. There are many examples online. Google for "android custom list" and u will find enough examples.

The idea is that you create a row.xml that reaembles what a single row should look like. Could be 2 textviews could be 10. In the adapter you tell the rows in the listview to use row.xml instead of standard rows.  For the custom adapter you will probably want to extend arrayadapter.

I am using my phone so i can't link examples.
Goodluck on your search. Its actually not so hard when u understand the proces.